# Customizing a Networkx graph (or Scatter) with Python Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly, networkx

I'm using Plotly's Python interface to generate a network. I've managed to create a network with my desired nodes and edges, and to control the size of the nodes. 
I am *desperately* looking for help on how to do the following:

1. add node labels
2. add edge labels according to a list of weights
3. control the edge line width according to a list of weights

All this without using the "hovering" option, as it has to go in a non-interactive paper. I'd greatly appreciate any help! [Plotly's output](https://plot.ly/~hagrid/2/amino-acid-substitution-rates-in-phosphorylation-sites/) | 
[In case this fails, the figure itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJJTJ.png) |
[matrix.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15uTdZ4BeyJg8wcvPeUK4nrh0lVHBE_Uz/view?usp=sharing)
This is my code (most is copy-pasted from the Plotly tutorial for Networkx):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import networkx as nx

matrix = pd.read_csv("matrix.csv", sep = "\t", index_col = 0, header = 0)

G = nx.DiGraph()

# add nodes:
G.add_nodes_from(matrix.columns)

# add edges:
edge_lst = [(i,j, matrix.loc[i,j])
            for i in matrix.index
            for j in matrix.columns
            if matrix.loc[i,j] != 0]
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edge_lst)

# create node trace:
node_trace = Scatter(x = [], y = [], text = [], mode = 'markers',
                    marker = Marker(
                    showscale = True,
                    colorscale = 'YIGnBu',
                    reversescale = True,
                    color = [],
                    size = [],
                    colorbar = dict(
                        thickness = 15,
                        title = 'Node Connections',
                        xanchor = 'left',
                        titleside = 'right'),
                    line = dict(width = 2)))

# set node positions
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
for node in G.nodes():
    G.node[node]['pos']= pos[node]

for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.node[node]['pos']
    node_trace['x'].append(x)
    node_trace['y'].append(y)

# create edge trace:
edge_trace = Scatter(x = [], y = [], text = [],
                     line = Line(width = [], color = '#888'),
                     mode = 'lines')

for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.node[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.node[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_trace['x'] += [x0, x1, None]
    edge_trace['y'] += [y0, y1, None]
    edge_trace['text'] += str(matrix.loc[edge[0], edge[1]])[:5]

# size nodes by degree
deg_dict = {deg[0]:int(deg[1]) for deg in list(G.degree())}
for node, degree in enumerate(deg_dict):
    node_trace['marker']['size'].append(deg_dict[degree] + 20)

fig = Figure(data = Data([edge_trace, node_trace]),
             layout = Layout(
                 title = '<br>AA Substitution Rates',
                 titlefont = dict(size = 16),
                 showlegend = True,
                 margin = dict(b = 20, l = 5, r = 5, t = 40),
                 annotations = [dict(
                     text = "sub title text",
                     showarrow = False,
                     xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
                     x = 0.005, y = -0.002)],
                 xaxis = XAxis(showgrid = False, 
                               zeroline = False, 
                               showticklabels = False),
                 yaxis = YAxis(showgrid = False, 
                               zeroline = False, 
                               showticklabels = False)))

py.plot(fig, filename = 'networkx')
```

Answer (score 5):

**So**

**1.** The solution to this is relative easy, you create a list with the node ids and you set it in the *text* attribute of the scatter plot. Then you set the mode as *"markers+text"* and you're done.

**2.** This is a little bit more tricky. You have to calculate the middle of each line and create a list of dicts including the line's middle position and weight. Then you add set as the layout's *annotation*.

**3.** This is too compicated to be done using plotly IMO. As for now I am calculating the position of each node using networkx *spring_layout* function. If you'd want to set the width of each line based on its weight you would have to modify the position using a function that takes into account all the markers that each line is attached to.

**Bonus** I give you the option to color each of the graph's components differently.

Here's a (slightly modified) function I made a while ago that does **1** and **2**:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import networkx as nx

def scatter_plot_2d(G, folderPath, name, savePng = False):
    print("Creating scatter plot (2D)...")

    Nodes = [comp for comp in nx.connected_components(G)] # Looks for the graph's communities
    Edges = G.edges()
    edge_weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')

    labels = [] # names of the nodes to plot
    group = [] # id of the communities
    group_cnt = 0

    print("Communities | Number of Nodes")
    for subgroup in Nodes:
        group_cnt += 1
        print("      %d     |      %d" % (group_cnt, len(subgroup)))
        for node in subgroup:
            labels.append(int(node))
            group.append(group_cnt)

    labels, group = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(labels, group))))

    layt = nx.spring_layout(G, dim=2) # Generates the layout of the graph
    Xn = [layt[k][0] for k in list(layt.keys())]  # x-coordinates of nodes
    Yn = [layt[k][1] for k in list(layt.keys())]  # y-coordinates
    Xe = []
    Ye = []

    plot_weights = []
    for e in Edges:
        Xe += [layt[e[0]][0], layt[e[1]][0], None]
        Ye += [layt[e[0]][1], layt[e[1]][1], None]
        ax = (layt[e[0]][0]+layt[e[1]][0])/2
        ay = (layt[e[0]][1]+layt[e[1]][1])/2
        plot_weights.append((edge_weights[(e[0], e[1])], ax, ay))

    annotations_list =[
                        dict(   
                            x=plot_weight[1],
                            y=plot_weight[2],
                            xref='x',
                            yref='y',
                            text=plot_weight[0],
                            showarrow=True,
                            arrowhead=7,
                            ax=plot_weight[1],
                            ay=plot_weight[2]
                        ) 
                        for plot_weight in plot_weights
                    ]

    trace1 = go.Scatter(  x=Xe,
                          y=Ye,
                          mode='lines',
                          line=dict(color='rgb(90, 90, 90)', width=1),
                          hoverinfo='none'
                        )

    trace2 = go.Scatter(  x=Xn,
                          y=Yn,
                          mode='markers+text',
                          name='Nodes',
                          marker=dict(symbol='circle',
                                      size=8,
                                      color=group,
                                      colorscale='Viridis',
                                      line=dict(color='rgb(255,255,255)', width=1)
                                      ),
                          text=labels,
                          textposition='top center',
                          hoverinfo='none'
                          )

    xaxis = dict(
                backgroundcolor="rgb(200, 200, 230)",
                gridcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                showbackground=True,
                zerolinecolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)"
                )
    yaxis = dict(
                backgroundcolor="rgb(230, 200,230)",
                gridcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                showbackground=True,
                zerolinecolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)"
                )

    layout = go.Layout(
        title=name,
        width=700,
        height=700,
        showlegend=False,
        plot_bgcolor="rgb(230, 230, 200)",
        scene=dict(
            xaxis=dict(xaxis),
            yaxis=dict(yaxis)
        ),
        margin=dict(
            t=100
        ),
        hovermode='closest',
        annotations=annotations_list
        , )
    data = [trace1, trace2]
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    plotDir = folderPath + "/"

    print("Plotting..")

    if savePng:
        plot(fig, filename=plotDir + name + ".html", auto_open=True, image = 'png', image_filename=plotDir + name,
         output_type='file', image_width=700, image_height=700, validate=False)
    else:
        plot(fig, filename=plotDir + name + ".html")
```

Comment: Regarding the second point, edges' labels, you can find a full documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-annotations) for the properties that you can twist and tweak.

Comment: October 2021: plotly is deprecated and should be replaced by chart_studio.

Answer (score 1):

The [d3graph library](https://erdogant.github.io/d3graph/) provides the functionalities you want.

```
pip install d3graph
```

I downloaded your data and imported it for demonstration:

```
# Import data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)

# Import library
from d3graph import d3graph

# Convert your Pvalues. Note that any edge is set when a value in the matrix is >0. The edge width is however based on this value. A conversion is therefore useful when you work with Pvalues.
df[df.values==0]=1
df = -np.log10(df)
# Increase some distance between edges. Maybe something like this.
df = (np.exp(df)-1)/10

# Make the graph with default settings
d3 = d3graph()

# Make the graph by setting some parameters
d3.graph(df)

# Set edge properties
d3.set_edge_properties(directed=True)

# Set node properties
d3.set_node_properties(color=df.columns.values, size=size, edge_size=10, edge_color='#000000', cmap='Set2')
```

This will result in an interactive network graph. Two screenshots: one with the default settings and the one with tweaked settings. More examples can be found [here](https://erdogant.github.io/d3graph/pages/html/Examples.html).

[image: Default settings]
[image: Tweaked d3graph]